# What could a user have changed to cause a projection / georeferencing problem in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, arcgis-10.0

We use shared mxd files on a network. Several users have older versions of Arcmap (10.0 specifically) that are no longer under ESRI maintenance. One of the mxds that we use is used by several users. One user opens the project and everything is fine but another user (user 2) opens the same project and the imagery does not align with the layers in the project. This is the same project that everyone in the organization uses but only this one user sees this issue (consistently the same person; aka user 2). The vector layers are in one space and the imagery is in another location. I tried removing the user's Normal.mxt file and that also did not fix the problem. I have also tried starting with a blank mxd and adding layers in. Something about this one SID mosaic image for this one user (and only this one user) is problematic. The raster is not in the GDB it is in a folder with an SDW file, an xml (for the sid) and another xml file for the aux.

I really don't understand this because the data frame, vector layers, and imagery are all in the same state plane coordinate system (MD FIPS 1900 in units of Feet). But the most puzzling thing is (as I mentioned above), no other users experience this. We have also been using this image since early in 2015. It previously worked fine for the user who is now experiencing this problem. I figure it is a long shot and the question is likely unable to be reproduced but if anyone has seen anything like this and would like to comment or demonstrate with an answer, it could prove very useful to me.

[image]

Coordinate System Info:
NAD_1983_StatePlane_Maryland_FIPS_1900_Feet
WKID: 2248 Authority: EPSG

Projection: Lambert_Conformal_Conic
False_Easting: 1312333.333333333
False_Northing: 0.0
Central_Meridian: -77.0
Standard_Parallel_1: 38.3
Standard_Parallel_2: 39.45
Latitude_Of_Origin: 37.66666666666666
Linear Unit: Foot_US (0.3048006096012192)

Geographic Coordinate System: GCS_North_American_1983
Angular Unit: Degree (0.0174532925199433)
Prime Meridian: Greenwich (0.0)
Datum: D_North_American_1983
  Spheroid: GRS_1980
    Semimajor Axis: 6378137.0
    Semiminor Axis: 6356752.314140356
    Inverse Flattening: 298.257222101

I noticed that in my image properties the spatial reference is unset but the user that is having the issue has the following image properties including units of meters which is incorrect. The units are feet (e.g. the 0.5 cell size since this is 6" imagery).

[image]

Comment: Is the raster stored in the geodatabase ? If yes, what type of geodatabase?

Comment: no it's in a folder (I edited the question).

Comment: How big is the offset? 1 pixel or hundreds of metres?

Comment: It is hundreds of meters. I'll see if I can add a screenshot.

Comment: SID format has some versions. Consider the version ofSID and Arcmap compatibility. I faced a problem with SID format in a project so i change SID to tiff. But the best solution is using mosaic Raster in Geodatabase (File GDB or in SDE).

Comment: Hmm.. I was going to suggest it was a rogue geo-processing environment setting at the _Application_ level which was never cleared and is being inherited, say a left in transformation from an old project? But 2.2 million feet is quite a displacement.

Comment: 1. You might try renaming the user's entire ESRI application data folder to see if that fixes things.  If not you might try renaming the ESRI folders in the Registry after backing it up.  These are frequent first fixes tried if you call ESRI tech support.  2.  A long shot but I've seen this with tifs.  You might check to see if the sid has georeferencing information in its header that is different from the world file.  All your other users might be relying on the header (the default I think in ArcMap options) but this person may have their ArcMap set to using the world file.

Comment: I don't think this is causing the problem, but what version of the NAD83 datum is your projection using? Newer ArcGIS versions support newer NAD83 datums that aren't always available in earlier versions. I seem to recall ArcGIS 10 not having NAD83(2011).

Comment: One possibility is that the problematic computer can't find the geoferencing information for the SID. It may have the coordinate system, but the actual SID extents are showing as 0,0 to xmaxcell, ymaxcell. Or it's reading the units as meters rather than feet.

Comment: @mkennedy - that sounds like a pretty reasonable explanation. I'll hover around the image and see what the coordinates look like. I'm still not sure how I'd fix it but that might help me narrow this down.

Comment: @mkennedy - it does appear to be reading as meters rather than feet. See my new 2nd screenshot. How can I get it to go back to undefined?

Comment: Oh yes. that did it. I cleared the spatial reference information and it works just fine. I wonder if someone tried to incorrectly define the spatial reference information on the image. Permissions are set to disallow any changes on the drive but maybe ArcMap saved some of that information for just that user?

Comment: Guess--there have been bugs with units/coordinate system in the raster code. Maybe that computer doesn't have a patch and/or the other computers were able to copy the .aux file locally but not this one.